# How to detect new/changes from multiple source tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, cdc

There are 3 source tables where new users can be added or existing user profile can be updated. There is also a master table that contains all users which is updated by a separate process.

I need create a new table that will refreshes daily and contains new/updated users by comparing the source tables against the master. The three source tables have some common fields but some are specific to a table.

I have tried doing a full join with null check to get new users and comparing fields to detect changes but the performance is really slow.
Is there a better way of doing this?

EG. Master table

| email | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test@gmail.com | va1 | 1 | 3 |
| test1@gmail.com | val2 | 1 | 4 |

Table1

| email | col1 | col2 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test1@gmail.com | val3 | 1 | 4 |
| test2@gmail.com | val2 | 1 | 4 |

Table2

| email | col1 | col2 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test@gmail.com | va7 | 1 | 10 |
| test3@gmail.com | val4 | 4 | 4 |

Table3

| email | col1 | col2 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test4@gmail.com | val5 | 2 | 2 |

Expected Result

```
| email           | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6|
| --------------- |----- |------|------|------|----- |-----|
| test@gmail.com  | va7  |  1   |    3 | null | 10   | null|
| test1@gmail.com | va3  |  1   |    4 |  4   | null | null|
| test2@gmail.com | va2  |  1   |  null|  4   | null | null|
| test3@gmail.com | va4  |  4   |  null| null |  4   | null|
| test4@gmail.com | va5  |  2   |  null| null | null |  2  |
```

Comment: Can you fix the formatting plz?

Comment: Formatting is broken.  Check your post after making it, to see it looks okay.